# How to pass an string instead of a file

Tags: python

I have this file called "lexparser.bat"

```
@echo off
:: Runs the English PCFG parser on one or more files, printing trees only
:: usage: lexparser fileToparse
java -mx150m -cp "*;" edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser -outputFormat "penn,typedDependencies" edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz %1
```

---

I have a text
Text = ['asdfd', 'ahksja',....]

and I tried to pass a sentence 'asdf' to lexparser.bat but it does not work.

```
for sentence in Text:
    parser = os.popen("lexparser.bat", sentence)
```

However, if I have my text with .txt format, it works

```
parser = os.popen("lexparser.bat", "file.txt")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The second parameter to `os.popen` is the *mode* to open the command in (like for *reading* or for *writing*). It doesn't accept a file name or any other "sentence." Please [edit] your question to clarify what you're really trying to do. Do you think it would be helpful for others to know what *lexparser.bat* does?

Comment: i am new in this page, i don`t know how to edit my question

Comment: Look for links on the page reading "[edit]." Like the one right here.

Comment: Yes, it's more clear, but when you say your code works when you pass a file name to `popen`, I still think you're wrong. As I explained before, that's not how `popen` works. Besides, the usage note in your batch file clearly states that it expects a file name, so that's what you need to give it. This has nothing to do with Python; Python can't make your batch file accept other things. You'll have to change your Java program for that.

Comment: Ohhhhh ok!! That's ok!! Thank you so much

Comment: Why the unaccept? Isn't what Rob just said the same as what my answer said? Are you still stuck?

Comment: Oh sorry !!! Dont be Angry, I am new here!! It Is ok !!! Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether this can be done and how depends on the syntax of this *lexparser* program, not on Python.

That said, as @RobKennedy suggested, this isn't how you pass an argument to `os.popen()`. You probably want `os.popen("lexparser.bat file.txt")`.

Or use [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) instead, as `os.popen` is [deprecated](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.popen). That would look like `subprocess.call(["lexparser.bat", "file.txt"])`.